# Why does Blender export only a few polygons when I want to export the full mesh?

Tags: export, .fbx

I have a mesh with an armature I want to export as an .FBX from Blender.  It's a humanoid figure.  When I try to export it, only the lacrimal (the tear duct part of the eyes) part of the mesh is exported, along with the armature.  The rest of the mesh is discarded during the export process.

This only happens with this one mesh; I don't have this problem with other objects, even the ones from the same source.  Any suggestions?

Edit: adding photos:

[image]

This is my work-in-progress in Blender.  I have added material zones for the figures skin and uniform, and I haven't gotten to his hair or metal parts yet.

[image]

This is when I export it and open it in Noesis.  Only the metal parts come through, minus the badge on the figure's chest.  The hair (which wasn't altered yet), the skin, and the uniform are missing.  The armature came through intact, but portions of the mesh are missing.

[image]

See, the armature is there.

Comment: There is an option that allows you to choose to export selected objects only, may be you should check that.

Comment: I've tried that, and it still happens; in fact, it's starting to happen with other meshes I've tried.  I've gone through all the export settings, and none of them has any other effect.

Comment: Can you upload the file? And/Or post a few screenshots? It may help solving this.

Comment: Photos added.  Any insight you can add would be appreciated.

Comment: you mention the mesh not appearing "when FBX opended in Noesis", what happens if you try to re-import the FBX into a (New) blend session?

Comment: Good notion.  I just tried it, and it re-imports into Blender just fine.  Maybe the problem is with Noesis.